# Is there any method or procedure to prevent jQuery to apply all the same classes except current class?

Tags: jquery, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I have situation to apply some jQuery to current class which should not apply to remaining classes of having same name. I want to apply jQuery code to apply to first "img_click" div but not to next "img_click"
Please find example code below:

```
    <div>    
      <div class="img_click">
        <img src="image1.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="info">
        <h2>Image Heading</h2>
        <div>Posted on..</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>    
      <div class="img_click">
        <img src="image2.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="info">
        <h2>Image Heading</h2>
        <div>Posted on..</div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**:

As you said *If you click n-th img_click class, then only the n-th info class should slideDown.* Hence go this way:

```js
$( "div.img_click" ).click(function (){$(this).next().slideDown();$(".info").not($(this).next()).css("display","none");});
```

```css
.info{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="img_click">
    <img src="image1.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <h2>Image Heading 1</h2>
    <div>Posted on.. </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="img_click">
    <img src="image2.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <h2>Image Heading 2</h2>
    <div>Posted on.. </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*If you don't want to hide previous `info` div then just **remove**:* `$(".info").not($(this).next()).css("display","none")`

Comment: Thank you Rk003. I have multiple img_click and info classes. If I click n-th img_click class, then only the n-th info class should slideDown. For example, if I click on 6th img_click class, then only the 6th info class should slideDown.

Comment: @GopiKrishna I edited my answer. Try about snippet, hope it will help you..

Comment: Thank you Ritesh. Your answer provided me another idea to solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can do with .find() :

```
$('h2').click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
    $this.closest('.main-class').find('.img_click').css( "border-color", "red" );

    });



.img_click{
  height:200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}



<div class="main-class">
  <div class="img_click">
   <img src="image1.jpg" /> 
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <h2>Image Heading</h2>
    <div>Posted on..</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="main-class">
  <div class="img_click">
   <img src="image2.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <h2 >Image Heading</h2>
    <div>Posted on..</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Akshita. I have multiple img_click and info classes. If I click n-th img_click class, then only the n-th info class should slideDown. For example, if I click on 6th img_click class, then only the 6th info class should slideDown.